# Reverse proxy on Apache (for QNAP)

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, dns, qnap

As I cannot access to ports other than 80 and 443 at work, I would like to make accessible some resources using Apache on my QNAP.

In particular I would like to:

1. set a Virtual Host (using sub1.domain.com) to connect to a service running on the same host (my QNAP) (http://localhost:58000)
2. set a Virtual Host (using sub2.domain.com) to connect to another host within the LAN (http://192.168.1.1:78080)
3. set a Virtual Host (using sub3.domain.com) to connect to an external website (e.g. https://www.google.com)

Beside activating proxy_module and proxy_ssl_module (and changing DNS accordingly), I have thought to use the following line codes on httpd-vhosts-user.conf (for 1. and 2.) and on httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf (for 3.):

General sections (FYI):

/etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts-user.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost _default_:80>
       DocumentRoot "/share/Web"
    </VirtualHost>
```

/etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:443

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
       DocumentRoot "/share/Web"
    </VirtualHost>
```

1. Virtual Host to connect to the service running on http://localhost:58000

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sub1.domain.com
      DocumentRoot "/share/Web/sub1"

      ProxyPreserveHost On 
      ProxyRequests Off 
      ProxyVia Off 
       ProxyPass /sub1 http://localhost:58000
       ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:58000 /sub1

      <Location /sub1>
         ProxyPassReverse /
         ProxyHTMLInterp On
         ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /sub1
         RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
      </Location>

      <Proxy *>
         AddDefaultCharset off
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      <Directory "/share/Web/sub1">
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
         Order allow,deny 
         Allow from all
      </Directory>   
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Virtual Host to connect to other service running on http://192.168.1.1:78080

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sub2.domain.com
      DocumentRoot "/share/Web/sub2"

      ProxyPreserveHost On 
      ProxyRequests Off 
      ProxyVia Off 
      ProxyPass /sub2 http://192.168.1.1:78080
      ProxyHTMLURLMap http://192.168.1.1:78080 /sub2

      <Location /Asus>
         ProxyPassReverse /
         ProxyHTMLInterp On
         ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /sub2
         RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
      </Location>

      <Proxy *>
         AddDefaultCharset off
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      <Directory "/share/Web/sub2">
         Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
         Order allow,deny 
         Allow from all
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Virtual Host to connect to the given external site (e.g. google) [credits to [kamal @ serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/295968/when-using-reverse-proxy-backend-server-does-301-back-to-the-proxy-server-or-ch)]

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName sub3.domain.com

      ProxyPreserveHost On

      <Proxy *>
         AddDefaultCharset off
         Order deny,allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from all
      </Proxy>

       ProxyPass /sub3 https://www.google.com/
       ProxyHTMLURLMap https://www.google.com /sub3

      <Location /sub3>
         ProxyPassReverse /
         ProxyHTMLInterp On
         ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /sub3
         RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
      </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

However none of these Virtual Hosts work (I have a connection fail or endless loading).

Could someone please help me reviewing the code?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers:

1. Virtual Host to connect to the service running on http://localhost:58000

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sub1.domain.com
   ProxyRequests Off
   <Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   <Location />
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Location>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:58000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:58000/
   ProxyStatus On
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Virtual Host to connect to other service running on http://192.168.1.1:78080

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sub2.domain.com
   ProxyRequests Off
   <Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   <Location />
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Location> 
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.1:78080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.1:78080/
   ProxyStatus On
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Virtual Host to connect to the given external site (e.g. google in HTTP only)

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sub3.domain.com
   DocumentRoot "/share/Web"
   <Directory "/share/Web">
   Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Deny from none
   </Directory>
   <Location />
   ProxyPass http://google.com/
   ProxyPassReverse http://google.com/
   </Location>
   </Virtualhost>
   ```